# Qt signal from thread causes error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qthread, qt-signals

I have a thread from which I need to send a signal with a parameter to a pointer like the following:

```
connect(insThread, SIGNAL(sgGetCurrentElement(QWebElement&)), this, SIGNAL(sgGetCurrentElement(QWebElement&)));
```

where insThread is the thred. However I got error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type ‘QWebElement&’ (Make sure ‘QWebElement&’ is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I already know that I need to use qRegisterMetaType but I couldn't figure out how I can construct it. I tried

```
qRegisterMetaType<QWebElement&>("myElement");
```

but failed. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: try qRegisterMetaType<QWebElement>("QWebElement");

Comment: Furthermore, you need to connect a SIGNAL to a SLOT. Try this `connect(insThread, SIGNAL(sgGetCurrentElement(QWebElement&)), this, SLOT(sgGetCurrentElement(QWebElement&)));`... Also, it seems your use a _sg_ prefix for the slot; maybe a mistake, too!

Comment: @Vince: not necessarily. It is fine to connect a signal to a signal if the second signal is then connected to a slot.

Comment: Even if the second signal is not connected to a slot, it's still fine, of course.

Comment: To a certain definition of fine, yes. It is pointless in an application with slot, I agree about that with Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to register the QWebElement with a reference (&) because have prototyped the slot to take QWebElement as a reference, but this is not a very good idea if you're posting the signal from one thread to another, see [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17660-Slots-amp-Signals-w-parameters-passed-by-reference). Anyway, as Laszlo pointed out, you have to register the base type, it is meaningless to register the type with the reference tag (&).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to register it with `&`, but do it without that as follows:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QWebElement>("myElement");
```